# Data Bindings Oddities in grails

Tags: grails

In grails I am trying to bind data to a command object, however I ran into a weird issue where a string postfix would automatically (silently) be stripped off a number. For example:

```
class MyCommand {
    int myInt
}
def test = {
    def cmd = new MyCommand()
    def myMap = [myInt:"123asdf"]
    bindData(cmd, myMap)
    boolean errors = cmd.hasErrors()
    render errors
}
```

This will render false and myInt will be set to 123.
However if I attempt to set myInt to "asdf123" cmd.hasErrors() will return true.

Why would this be happening? Is there a different way to bind data to an object that will handle this.
The same issue is talked about in this post but does not offer any solution: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Data-binding-with-numbers-is-this-expected-td2073860.html

Comment: Doing cmd.properties=myMap has the same results. But cmd.properties['myInt']=myMap throws a GroovyCastException with this message: "Cannot cast object '123asdf' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'"

Comment: This bug has been reported to grails, and is tracked here http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6766

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the answer you want, however, I think this is what you need. I've done a lot of research on this and it seems to me that data binding will not always (hint never) return the form the exact data the user entered when dealing with invalid numbers. My suggestion to you, after a lot of research, is to do wrap the conversion of the text to an integer with a try catch and if it fails, set it to null. Then pass the params back to the view. If the value is null, get the value from the params.